# Kriging with positivity constraint using the STK toolbox

Tags: kriging

I work in the aerospace world, specifically doing calibration and characterization of detectors and space instruments (cubesats, space spectrographic satellites etc.) We always need to interpolate our datasets to fully characterize an instrument i.e. a satellite may need to view light from 300nm to 2300nm. In the lab we can use a laser at a few wavelengths, but then rely on interpolation to complete our calibrations. Kriging seems like a great tool for this as ultimately the calibration is defined by its uncertainty, and the variances computed via kriging can be used to calculate them.

I have one specific question, that may not be a typical question for this tool. Is there a way to set any limits on a krig interpolation? The exact problem I have is that I have some recorded line shapes, that I fit some distribution to. I am then using kriging to interpolate the coefficients of the fit. Some of the coefficients cannot go below zero (it makes no physical sense i.e. Gaussian width cannot be<0), so I am trying to see if there is a way to limit the kriged value to > 0.

Comment: You likely don't want Kriging for this: some kind of *monotonic interpolator* is what you need.  But details matter, so if you can provide a simple, clear, well-described example of your problem, you are likely to get much more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically for the [STK toolbox](https://github.com/stk-kriging/stk/) (since you mention it in the title of your post): one possible, simple approach is to transform the data to get rid of the positivity constraint.

For instance, you can take the log of your positive data, and then map the kriging predictions and confidence intervals back to the original domain using the exponential.  (Other mappings may turn out to be more suitable to your particular case.)

Another approach is to used some form of "constrained kriging" [a,b] but this is not readily available in the STK toolbox at the moment.

References:

[a] S. Da Veiga & A. Marrel (2012), [Gaussian process modeling with inequality constraints](http://www.numdam.org/item/AFST_2012_6_21_3_529_0/), Annales de la faculté des sciences de Toulouse Mathématiques, 21(3), 529-555.

[b] H. Maatouk & X. Bay (2017) [Gaussian process emulators for computer experiments with inequality constraints](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11004-017-9673-2), Mathematical Geosciences, 49, 557–582.